# Branching in flowcharts

Tags: flowchart

I usually use UML to communicate my ideas for software development. Unfortunately, with my current project I am having to create flowcharts to represent requirements to customers and my boss. One problem that I am having right now is that I need to represent some kind of branching in my diagrams. The system involves users joining groups and the users need to have discovered the group before joining one. For example, they may have done a keyword search. Or they may have browsed categories. How do I represent this kind of branching in flowcharts?

Answer (score 1):

Normally a "decision" diamond. Do you have something more complex that you can't handle this way?

A couple of approaches spring to mind:

- One decision "Group discovery" - 1 branch if "browsed", other branch
  if "searched"
- Multiple "chained" decisions - "User searched" Y/N, "User browsed"
  Y/N
- Either of the above, , but do it earlier (i.e. branch at the point the user finds their group).

Comment: The problem is the user does not have to make any decisions here. They just go through some processes and arrive at the joining stage. Even if I use the decision diamond, I wonder what kind of decision they would have to make.